# Haskell - parse error/ using multiple where clauses

Tags: list, haskell, set, where-clause

when trying to define a function that would remove the largest subset of set **m** that is also a subset of set **a** from set **a**, I encountered the following error:

```
filename.hs:7:33:parse error (possibly incorrect indentation)
```

for the following code:

```
exclude :: Integral t => [t] -> [t] -> [t]
a `exclude` m
           | m == [] = a
           | a == (b ++ c) = b
           | otherwise = []
           where b /= []
           where c = [z | z <- m]
```

how do I implement multiple conditions/definitions (using **where** or otherwise), or correct the function to properly work in a different way?

Comment: What is the intention of `where b /= []`?

Comment: Is the intended result the list of those elements of `a` that are not elements of `m`?

Comment: the intended result was indeed all elements of a that are not also elements of m. btw, thanks for the help on the syntax Daniel, even though it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: **a 'exclude' m = filter (`notElem` m) a** worked. thanks joachifm/ Christian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saying "the largest subset of set `m` that is also a subset of set `a`"
is the same as saying "all elements of `m` that are also elements of `a`".

Then the solution to your problem is stated simply as:

```
exclude a = filter (`notElem` a)
```

which when applied to `m` will give you a subset of `m` modulo any elements
that are also members of `a`. That is, it will "remove the largest subset of
`m` that is also a subset of `a`".

Comment: +1 for cutting through everything and ending up with an elegant, readable and understandable one-liner.

Comment: -1 for not asking the question. Sorry, I came here for the `where`.

Comment: @ziggystar, the question asks for solutions "using **where** or otherwise," or even solutions that "correct the function to properly work in a different way." It seems to me that joachifm answered the question as asked, so I don't see why they should be punished.

Answer (score 5):

One part of your question is easily answerable. You can have multiple definitions in one `where` clause, as in

```
foo n
    | even r = bar
    | s < 12 = baz
    | otherwise = quux
      where
        r = n `mod` 1357
        h = a + b
          where
            (a,b) = r `divMod` 53    -- nested where-clause
        s = r - 3*h
```

and you can have nested `where`-clauses. But in a `where`-clause, you can only have definitions. Conditions would go into the guards (or `if then else` expressions on the right hand side) and can be combined with the boolean operators, `(&&)`, `(||)`, `not` ...

As for your code, so far I haven't figured out what you intended it to do.

Answer (score 0):

In fact，there is a function in Data.List and Data.Set called '\'. I'll show '\' function of Data.List .

```
import Data.List
exclude :: Integral t => [t] -> [t] -> [t]
a `exclude` m = a\\m
```